# How to use the Dictionary javascript class in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, object, dictionary, google-apps-script

I am trying to make and use a Dictionary object in Google Apps Script. Before, I used a very long switch statement for my script the first time around, and when I submitted it to the Gallery, the person who approved it asked why I didn't use a Javascript Dictionary object instead. I looked into how to use Dictionary objects, but now my script wont' work because Google Apps Script doesn't understand the command:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Dict.jsm");
```

This 'import' line of code was copied straight from this Javascript Reference webpage:
http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Dict.jsm

How do I include this javascript library needed to make it work, or what is the Google Apps Script alternative to a javascript Dictionary object?

Comment: I don't think that's what the person meant by "dictionary object".

Answer (score 6):

Any time you've got a `switch` statement that looks something like:

```
switch ( someValue ) {
case "string1": doSomething( valueForString1 ); break;
case "string2": doSomething( valueForString2 ); break;
// ... 
case "stringN": doSomething( valueForStringN ); break;
}
```

you can replace that with:

```
var dict = {
  "string1": valueForString1,
  "string2": valueForString2,
  // ...
  "stringN": valueForStringN
};

doSomething( dict[ someValue ] );
```

The values can be anything, of course: strings, numbers, objects, functions, whatever.  And you probably would want to check for a value being missing from the dictionary:

```
if (dict[someValue]) doSomething(dict[someValue]);
```

Comment: Any Time ... how would a dictionary treat common objects as keys, like an identity map or would it derive an optionally non-unique string as key?

Comment: @SamGinrich this answer is old, and traditional JavaScript objects have property names that are strictly strings. The more recent Map class allows arbitrary objects as keys, but it doesn't work the way things do in Java (for example) because there's no concept of a type-based customized equality mechanism. In JavaScript an array as a key is only going to be equal to itself when tested as a Map key. Another array with identical contents would not be equal.

Comment: Thank you for the accurate response! Came here while trying to add a tree structure with a logical parent relation to the "flat heap" of the Google Docs ... as adding an object id as property failed, the fallback is the linear search in an array of pairs :(